# One function to toggle multiple hidden elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is just a snippet but I will have many different links on a page.  Each link will have a different hidden element associated with it.  I'm trying to avoid writing 100 different slideToggle statements for each of the links to bring up their respective hidden elements.  Is this anywhere near to that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<link href='favicon.ico' rel='icon' type='image/jpg'/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.county{ font:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.countystats{
    background-color:blue;
    display:none;
}



</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.county').click(function(){
          $(this).find('.countystats').slideToggle('fast')
          });
</script>




<a class="county" href="javascript:;" >one</a><br/>
<a class="county" href="javascript:;"> two</a>
</div>
<div class="countystats">stats one</div>
<div class="countystats">stats two</div>
<br />
<br/>
</body></html>
```

I would like for the link 'one' to show the div 'stats one' and link 'two' show the div for 'stats two'.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
$('.county').click(
    function(){
        var thisIs = $(this).index();
        $('.countystats').eq(thisIs).slideToggle(300);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ANu83/).

Note that I removed the `br` from the html to get the `index()` accurately. If you need `a` elements to be one-per-line, use:

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

References:

- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).

Comment: @ramblinman: if this was of use to you, please feel free to up-vote and/or accept :)

Comment: Good implementation, only downside is that it requires the links and div's to be in exactly the same order. As long as that is guaranteed this should work fine.

Comment: @InfernalBadger: that's absolutely true, yeah. But I'd imagine that, if they're being dynamically added, that assumption would hold. If not there is another way, based on the text-content of the `div` to show. But it's a fair bit slower, I think. Plus, more pronlematically, I doubt the text is going to be quite as simple as `'stats' + $(this).text()` So this felt like the cleanest method.

Comment: I agree, for his situation it should work fine. Much better than trying to check the text

Answer (score 1):

You may use given below toggle function to toggle multiple elements by
giving array of element id as input.

For example:

> ```
>      toggleElements(["elem1","elem2"],["elem3"]);
>      OR
>      toggleElements(arr1,arr2);
> ```

```
function showElements(showEls){
       for(var i=0; i<showEls.length; i++){
           if($("#"+showEls[i]).is(':hidden')) $("#"+showEls[i]).show();
       }
}
function hideElements(hideEls){
       for(var i=0; i<hideEls.length; i++){
          if($("#"+hideEls[i]).is(':visible')) $("#"+hideEls[i]).hide();
       }
}

function toggleElements(arr1,arr2){
        if(true){
            if($("#"+arr1[0]).is(":hidden")){
                 showElements(arr1);
                 hideElements(arr2);
            }else{
                 showElements(arr2);
                 hideElements(arr1);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would ideally need a way to link the links to the right div. You can do this using the data attributes like this.

HTML:

```
<a class="county" data-divId="stats1" href="#">one</a><br/>
<a class="county" data-divId="stats2" href="#">two</a>
<div id="stats1" class="countystats">stats one</div>
<div id="stats2" class="countystats">stats two</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.county').click(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).data('divId')).slideToggle();
});
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/6wDf9/

This should be quite easy to do if you are dynamically generating these links.