# Function to toggle dynamically-added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One function to toggle multiple hidden elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327441/one-function-to-toggle-multiple-hidden-elements)

I saw this working in a jsFiddle but for whatever reason I can't get it to work.  The code is the way it is because I will have 100+ links from which to choose and I didn't want to make 100 different slideToggle functions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.county').click(
    function(){
        var thisIs = $(this).index();
        $('.countystats').eq(thisIs).slideToggle(300);
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.county{ font:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.countystats{
    background-color:blue;
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>



<div>
    <a class="county" href="javascript:;">one</a>
    <a class="county" href="javascript:;">two</a>
</div>
<div class="countystats">stats one</div>
<div class="countystats">stats two</div>
<br />
<br/>
</body></html>
```

working jsFiddle url: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ANu83/

Comment: Why have you posted a 2nd question about this rather than commenting in the other one? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327441/one-function-to-toggle-multiple-hidden-elements/5327511#5327511

Comment: because i finally created an account so i could login and give people credit for their answers :)

Comment: Ok, did you try my answer from the previous question?

Comment: i did.  and it didn't work :/.

Comment: is "jquery.js" the right path, also are there any javascript errors shown?

Comment: no, there are no errors.  the jquery path is correct as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend changing the .click to a .live to allow any dynamically added content to also honor the click.. and wrap it in a document.ready so it doesn't matter where in the document the script is.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.county').live('click',function(){
            var thisIs = $('.county').index($(this));
            alert(thisIs);
            $('.countystats').eq(thisIs).slideToggle(300);
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution given to you previously relies on two things.

- The links are nested in a specific order within a single div having no elements between them (ie `<br/>`)
- The countystats divs immediately follow the div that contains the links.

If it still doesn't work it would be much more helpful to post a your non-working code than the working example.

Comment: that is a non-working example.  at least according to firefox and chrome.

Comment: that doesn't change whether or not it works.  if using this index() method isn't the best, do you know of another technique to use to do what i'd like? thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Working version follows.  Your code has two issues

The code that is supposed to "go through all of the things that are class=county and assign an event handler" executes before any of those things are defined.  So it finds none.  I moved that script to a position after those tags are created.

The line in the event handler that does var thisIs = $(this).index(); - I have no idea why this works in jsfiddle (maybe a different version of jquery?)  It doesn't work at all in my browser.  I rewrote it slightly below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.county{ font:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.countystats{
    background-color:blue;
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <a class="county" href="javascript:;">one</a>
    <a class="county" href="javascript:;">two</a>
</div>
<div class="countystats">stats one</div>
<div class="countystats">stats two</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.county').click(
    function(){
        var thisIs = $('.county').index(this);
        $('.countystats').eq(thisIs).slideToggle(300);
    });
</script>
</body></html>
```